# Step By Step Help For Recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have gone to many online text tutorials, asked my teacher, attempted to go through questions to gain a more thorough knowledge of recursion however I am still struggling with understanding how to implement it. I understand the definition as it involves a function calling itself and the fact it is used to write certain parts of code much more efficiently and in a more compact manner.

I am especially having trouble understanding how recursion works and how to implement it to go through items in a list. For a problem set given to us, we are required to use recursion to go through and find specific items within the list. The part that gets me confused is the [H|T] part of the list and how to list the items that match a condition and list them in a new list.

**Would anyone please give me small example with each step explained that I can use as a guide to try to figure out my problem set independently.** It would really by helpful, being new to Prolog through reading ahead I know it is a vital skill that I will need to master to use the language much more efficiently.

Your kind help would be great.

Comment: The best explanation I have seen is in the book:
Clause and Effect: Prolog Programming for the Working Programmer

Answer (score 0):

A list in Prolog is a very simple data structure:

- An empty list is the prolog atom `[]`.
- A non-empty list is the prolog term `.(H,T)`, where

  - `H` is the list item at the beginning of the list, and
  - 'T' is the tail of the list, which is another prolog list.

The tail of the last list node — the innermost list node, if you want to look at it that way — is the empty list. Everything else is a non-empty list.

Prolog's square bracket notation for lists (`[a,b,c]`) is simply syntatic sugar on the above data structure.

- `[]` is the empty list
- `[a]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,[])`.
- `[a,b]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,.(b,[]))`.
- `[a,b,c]` is exactly equivalent to `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`.
- and so on (one can readily see why one might prefer the square bracket notation over the `./2` notation).

The Head/Tail operator `|` is just more syntactic sugar:

- `[H|T]` is exactly equivalent to `.(H,T)`.

And when I say *exactly equivalent* above, I mean *unifiable with*. If you say something like

```
[A,B,C] = .(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
```

It will evaluate as `true` (success) and you'll get

```
A = a, B = b , C = c
```

So, here's a simple, annotated example of list traversal for you:

```
member_of_list(_,[])      :- % the empty list has no members.
  fail.                      % - so we fail (Note that this clause is redundant, since it will fail appropriately without it.)
member_of_list(X,[X|Xs] ).   % X is a member of the non-empty list, if it is found at the head of the list.
member_of_list(X,[_|Xs] ) :- % otherwise, we discard the head of the list, and
  member_of_list(X,Xs).      %  recurse down on the tail of the list.
```

It might help if you work through it in the debugger, or add some logging to it to so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Nicholas - your second clause is missing a goal (:- true. or just . instead of :-).